# Should I wait for the prayer leader to say “Yishtabach” after “Pesukei dezimrah”?

Tags: halacha, minhag, blessing, tzibur-community, shacharis-morning-prayer

“Yishtabach” is the closing blessing of the “Pesukei dezimrah”.

If a worshipper has concluded the pesukei dezimrah, should he wait to say Yishtabach with the prayer leader or should he say it directly he finishes? I have observed people choosing the former, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Magen Avraham in Shuchan Aruch siman 53:4 says that an individual who reaches Yishtabach should say it right away.

Comment: +1. Does he mention whether this is only on a weekday or even on _Shabas_ and _yom tov_?

Comment: The Magen Avraham says, "וכן בשבת אם גמר פסוקי דזמרה קודם הש"ץ יאמר ישתבח מיד". Translation: Similarly, on Shabbat, if he finished Pesukei dezimrah before the Chazan, he should say Yishtabach immediately.